# How to localize downloaded images in iOS app

Tags: swift, xcode

We have an application that needs to support multiple languages, both in text strings and photos.  We would like to have our users be able to specify a language and have all of those files downloaded at runtime, since there are a lot of files.  I have been looking for threads on best practices for this, and I haven't found much. I was wondering if anyone has experience with this type of thing.  My ideas to solve the problem are:

1. Download the files into the sandboxed area and localize the folder programmatically (if that's possible)
2. Download the files and then move them into a localized folder of images

Does anyone have any experience with this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processs is very easy you need to create a folder in Application support / documents with the key of the language dynamically ( sure it's possible with [This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1415371-createdirectory) ) such as

```
en -> file.text
   -> images -> img1.png
             -> img2.png

fr-> file.text
   -> images -> img1.png
             -> img2.png
```

and so on , then according to your app setting load from the folder , another way is to use SdWebImage and create your images urls in this manner

```
https://www.dom1.com/en/img1
https://www.dom1.com/fr/img1
```

en/fr according to the current setting , if it's a patch of images , then method 1 is fitting perfectly

---

Suppose you have a setting like

```
 let current = UserDefaults.shared.string(forKey:"CurrentLang") // gives en / fr
```

then make `current` a global var that you use in any method or string composition  that's has a reference to text/image donwloaded content inside all the app

Comment: But this wouldn't allow me to use the automatic localization that takes place when changing the project language, correct? I'd have to check the language setting every time I wanted to display a file or string, correct?

Comment: when you change the language , change the global var after that any new vc shows should load from the changed language

Comment: I already have the language setting in there, and I definitely know how to save files.  I'm wondering if there's a way to save the files that would allow me to use the localization stuff that's built in.  Like when you have a localized image and it will automatically choose that image based on the project language.

Comment: the build in localization is signed with the main bundle that you can't change or add to  , this is the only way to accomplish this

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I like the idea of using the var for string composition to access the files.